# Reading large .csv file in android

Tags: java, android, database, csv

For my android application, I am using an AutoCompleteTextView. I want it so that the user types in a few letters of a city and there will be a popup showing the cities that match those letters. But, in order to do this, I need the list of all the city names. I have a .csv file and a .sql file containing all the data of the cities in the world. However, I do not know how to read such a large file effeciently. The file is approximetely 50 MB. Can someone please help me read or store this file so I can use it in my AutocompleteTextview? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create android app greater than 50 mb, or you must use [APK extension files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html).

With raw csv "cities" file with size of 50 mb or more, data base will be too big anyway. For you needs better solution will be access to online data base, store data online and read it from your app. I am sure, you can use some google API for it.

Comment: I used the google maps api before, but it takes too long for the results to show

Comment: But too long because query time or your connection speed? Using google service for action like this should be best solution, however, you can  use your own online data base. I am not sure how it work for autocomplete, because searching that big data base need some time.

Comment: Ok, I guess i will do that then.